# Confused on how to make variable in class?

Tags: java, android, json

I have a class (public class SaveTheFeed extends AsyncTask {)
and within the class I have a protected void that gets and interprets certain JSON info. I want to save different portions of the JSON as String to use later in the code. Simply writing `String fajr = cityObject.getString("fajr");` doesn't seem to work, and I can't use the public modifier either. How to I create these strings?

Here is the protected void:

```
        protected void outputTimings(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        String[] prayers = {"fajr", "shurooq", "dhuhr", "asr", "maghrib", "isha"};
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject cityObject =
                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                // for(int z=0; z < cityObject.length(); z++) {

                //Log.d("result", String.valueOf(prayers[i++]));
                result = result + "fajr" + " : "
                        + cityObject.getString("fajr") + "\n" + result + "shurooq" + " : "
                        + cityObject.getString("shurooq") + "\n" + result + "dhuhr" + " : "
                        + cityObject.getString("dhuhr") + "\n" + result + "asr" + " : "
                        + cityObject.getString("asr") + "\n" + result + "maghrib" + " : "
                        + cityObject.getString("maghrib") + "\n" + result + "isha" + " : "
                        + cityObject.getString("isha") + "\n";




            }
```

I want to create variables for the String values of the prayers

Comment: just declare variable globally

Comment: You're asking us to do an awful lot of mind reading.

Comment: Well what do you need to know, Im awfully new to this...

Comment: Please post relevant parts of your code

Comment: @ajb done added code

Comment: What do you mean "the values of the prayers"?  If `s` is a `String`, `String.valueOf(s)` just returns `s`.  Not very useful.  The code is helpful but your question still is not close to being clear.

Comment: Forgive me. `cityObject.getString("fajr")` returns a value from a bunch of JSON data. I want to be able to take that value and set it as a global variable

Comment: @SagarChavada I already tried (Using `public static final`) and I get an error on the first two modifiers saying that they are not allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well @Fencer300,

Simply make a simple bean class (Model class with getter setter methd )

```
// make a city bean class
public class cityModel implements Serializable {
private String fajr;

// do for more same ass

public String getFajr() {
    return fajr;
}

public void setFajr(String fajr) {
    this.fajr= fajr;
}
```

}

```
protected void outputTimings(JSONArray jsonArray) {
    String[] prayers = {"fajr", "shurooq", "dhuhr", "asr", "maghrib", 
"isha"};
    cityModel cityObj;
    try {
        cityObj= new cityModel();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject cityObject =
                    jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            // for(int z=0; z < cityObject.length(); z++) {
            cityObj.setFajr(""+cityObject.getString("fajr"))
            // do for more same as

        }
}
```

Note easily now you can use fajr value , do for same foe all

Comment: Where you want to pirnt the value simple make use like this
     cityModel cityObj= new cityModel();

     String fajr=cityObj.getFajr();

    Any where you can get and use.

Comment: When I do that it returns the variable as null

Answer (score 0):

Making the string the return value from the asynctask should make it available to the recursive class above. I know it partly defeats the reason for asynctask, but you may need to use

AsyncTask().execute(string, string).get();

to make class wait for return value, else I guess possible risks of race condition. I hope this helps.

Relevant Android docs, see get():

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html